# How to achieve the following layout?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Im trying to get the following layout, but missing something so I couldn't get it proper.
[image]

```
.wrapper{display:inline-block;}
.image{float:left;}
```

[Here is my fiddle !](http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/)

What would be the best style suggestions for title and sub-title.
Shall I use `<span>` tags? or `<h1>` and `<p>` tags?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yea, everything looking good, but can we have some relevant code so that we can debug?

Comment: I'd use `<h1>` for the title and `<p>` for the subtitle

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: added the fiddle, I'm not sure abt the styles of title and subtitle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/6/

Comment: @MiķelisJankovskis Thanks, but cant we attain this without putting h1 and p into another div?

Comment: I wasn't putting any p or h1, you miss-matched with somethung other.

Comment: sorry @MiķelisJankovskis, I meant to say, `<div>Title</div>` & `<div>Content</div>` are nested under `<div class="right">`. Can't we avoid the outer div for Title & Content ? 
Because if the content grows, the whole `<div class="right">` breaks down the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle - with spacing around the three components](http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/10/)
[Second Fiddle - without spacing around components](http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/13/)

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I set the title to a `<h1>` tag and the sub-title to a `<p>` tag. This set-up keeps the two entities from being on the same line.

I also added some margin's (the spacing you wanted around each component), borders, and background colors to be more like your desired styling.

Because you wanted the **content/sub-title to be cut off at the bottom of your image**, and your image was not going to always be a set resolution, I added a javascript method to iterate through your DOM, specifically on your `.wrapper` `div`'s and dynamically set the height of your sub-title/content. I did this by taking the calculated height of your image `.offsetHeight` and subtracting it from the height your title and spacing will always take up.

```
var wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
for(var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++){
    var wrapper = wrappers[i];
    var height = wrapper.getElementsByClassName("image")[0].offsetHeight;
    wrapper.getElementsByClassName("sub")[0].setAttribute("style","height:"+(height - 55) + "px");
}
```

On your sub-title/content I set a height and `overflow-y:hidden`, this will cut off your sub-title/content if it flows past the bottom of your image.

Please see the updated fiddle at the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
max height will not help me, if the image size is changing dynamically. And you can see h1 tag starts for the beginning of the image (since background extends from there), only text starts as we want. Im getting the same.

Comment: Updated my answer and expanded on explanations - I also added some javascript so max height will work for your now, because the heights of the sub-title are dynamically set after page load. You'll see all three entries/wrappers on the fiddle have different image sizes and the sub-title is cut off at the bottom as you desired in your question.

Comment: Great work ! 
I have one more query. When I am trying to remove all border and padding values (since i want no space between contents) its not working fine. Can u help me in fixing this http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/12/

Comment: I changed the content's tag from `<p>` to `<div>`. So it works fine now ! But I'm not sure why it gives a margin-bottom if I use `<p>` (even if `margin:0px;`)

Comment: Happy to be of assistance! I'm not sure why `margin:0px` in the `.sub` selector didn't work for you - it appears to work for me with the `<p>` tag in FireFox 26.0, Chrome  32.0.1700.107 m, and IE 11.0.9600.16518 on Windows 7 with [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/exXfD/13/) Well anyway, glad you have what you need! have fun =)

Comment: ThanQ Arty! the fiddle works for me even. Hope this code follows the standards. ThanQ for your patience once again... :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I may structure this depending on context:

http://codepen.io/aaronlsilber/pen/LjuFb

You'll notice I've kept the CSS fairly object-oriented. You may want to take a look at something like www.smacss.com — it'll change the way you write css!

Also, this reminds me of the media object:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

Comment: Yea @aaron, its takes time for me understand your style of writing CSS. Sure I ll look into the links you shared !

Comment: Thank you @aaron, your snippet is great too, but I can select only one as answer ! Happy to have your support !!